# Tried writing a loop statement that prints out my playlist, but my browser just infinitely loops instead

Tags: javascript, html, loops, infinite-loop

So, I am to write a loop statement that prints out my playlist, but my browser just infinitely loops instead of loading the text and the content. How could I adjust my code to do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>9. Looping Statements in Javascript</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>9. Looping Statements in Javascript</h1>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <div id="playlist"></div>
        <script>
            var playlist = [];
            playlist[0] = "Willy Wesly";
            playlist[1] = "Childish Gambino";
            playlist[2] = "Chance The Rapper";
            playlist[3] = "Travi$ Scott";
            playlist[4] = "Yeezy";

            // while
            var i = 0;
            while (i < playlist.length); {
                var element = document.getElementById('playlist').innerHTML = playlist;
                element.innerHTML = 'Now Playing: ' + playlist[i], i++;
                container.appendChild(element);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ; - after while condition could be problem... Script stops there, and...  while (i < playlist.length) { - this will work.

Answer (score 4):

Try this Remove the semicolon after the while closing brackets:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < playlist.length) {
    var element = document.getElementById('playlist').innerHTML = playlist;
    element.innerHTML = 'Now Playing: ' + playlist[i], i++;
    container.appendChild(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to append the element, it's already part of the dom.  just add to its `innerHTML`, (The br's are just how I think it would look prettiest)

```
var i = 0;
var element = document.getElementById('playlist');
element.innerHTML = 'Now Playing:<br/>';

while (i++ < playlist.length) {
    element.innerHTML += playlist[i] + '<br/>';
}
```